# Как лучше писать данный метод на PHP

Tags: php

Как, по Вашему мнению корректнее? :

```
public function add(\Data\Group $group, $name, \Data\Type $type, $required = false, $sort = NULL): ?\Data\Field {
        
        $field = new \Data\Field;
        $field->data_group = $group->id;
        $field->name = $name;
        $field->type = $type->id;
        $field->required = $required? : 0;
        $field->sort = $sort;

        return $this->dao->add($field)?:NULL;
        
    }
```

ИЛИ

```
    $field = new \Data\Field;
    $field->data_group = $group->id;
    $field->name = $name;
    $field->type = $type->id;
    $field->required = $required ? : 0;
    $field->sort = $sort;
    
    public function add(\Data\Field $field): ?\Data\Field {
        
        return $this->dao->add($field)?:NULL;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Это вопрос области [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), а не текущего проекта. Но, отвечая на ваш вопрос, по моему мнению второй вариант куда перспективнее. Единственное, что смущает: `$field->required = $required? : 0;`. Странный тернарный оператор...

Comment: $required получено из формы от checkbox'а и имеет значение on или NULL, а в объекте оно Boolean. Если не сложно - объясните, в чем более перспективен второй вариант?

Comment: @GlebTer тут перспектива в том, что вы конфигурируете объект как вам надо заранее. Это поможет сделать более гибко другие аналогичные задачи.